# Question regarding log marginal likelihood in SKLearn

Tags: scikit-learn, gaussian-process, bayesian-optimization

I'm trying to understand the hyperparameter optimization implemented in SKLearn. I'm using the basic example presented [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/gaussian_process/plot_gpr_noisy_targets.html) with an alternative data set of 100 observations of Rastrigin test function (see code below). I copy pasted the internal functions of `GP.fit` and `GP.log_marginal_likelihood` to play around with them.

When optimizing this model I normally get a log-marginal-likelihood value of 569.619 leading to the following GP which looks pretty messy regarding the confidence interval:

[image]

Since I often heard that the log-marginal-likelihood value should be positive, I added the following if-condition into the respective function to penalize negative LML values (disregarding that this is extremly bad style, especially for the optimizer):

```
    if log_likelihood < 0:
        log_likelihood = -np.inf
```

When I re-tested the fitting I get LMLs of about 404.084 and the following GP, which seem to be the better fitting model:

[image]

- **Which is the better fitting model?**
- **Why does the model with a lower LML seem to fit better when we are trying to minimize the negative LML, thus maximizing the LML?**

```
print(__doc__)

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C

import warnings
from operator import itemgetter

import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import cholesky, cho_solve, solve_triangular
import scipy.optimize

from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin, clone
from sklearn.base import MultiOutputMixin
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, ConstantKernel as C
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_array
from sklearn.utils.optimize import _check_optimize_result
from sklearn.utils.validation import _deprecate_positional_args

np.random.seed(1)

def alt_log_marginal_likelihood(gp, theta=None, eval_gradient=False, clone_kernel=True):

    if theta is None:
        if eval_gradient:
            raise ValueError(
                "Gradient can only be evaluated for theta!=None")
        return gp.log_marginal_likelihood_value_

    if clone_kernel:
        kernel = gp.kernel_.clone_with_theta(theta)
    else:
        kernel = gp.kernel_
        kernel.theta = theta

    if eval_gradient:
        K, K_gradient = kernel(gp.X_train_, eval_gradient=True)
    else:
        K = kernel(gp.X_train_)

    K[np.diag_indices_from(K)] += gp.alpha
    try:
        L = cholesky(K, lower=True)  # Line 2
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
        return (-np.inf, np.zeros_like(theta)) if eval_gradient else -np.inf

    y_train = gp.y_train_
    if y_train.ndim == 1:
        y_train = y_train[:, np.newaxis]

    alpha = cho_solve((L, True), y_train)  # Line 3

    log_likelihood_dims = -0.5 * np.einsum("ik,ik->k", y_train, alpha)
    log_likelihood_dims -= np.log(np.diag(L)).sum()
    log_likelihood_dims -= K.shape[0] / 2 * np.log(2 * np.pi)
    log_likelihood = log_likelihood_dims.sum(-1)  # sum over dimensions

    if eval_gradient:  # compare Equation 5.9 from GPML
        tmp = np.einsum("ik,jk->ijk", alpha, alpha)  # k: output-dimension
        tmp -= cho_solve((L, True), np.eye(K.shape[0]))[:, :, np.newaxis]

        log_likelihood_gradient_dims = 0.5 * np.einsum("ijl,jik->kl", tmp, K_gradient)
        log_likelihood_gradient = log_likelihood_gradient_dims.sum(-1)

    if log_likelihood < 0:
        log_likelihood = -np.inf

    if eval_gradient:
        return log_likelihood, log_likelihood_gradient
    else:
        return log_likelihood

def alt_fit(gp, X, y):

    if gp.kernel is None:  # Use an RBF kernel as default
        gp.kernel_ = C(1.0, constant_value_bounds="fixed") * RBF(1.0, length_scale_bounds="fixed")
    else:
        gp.kernel_ = clone(gp.kernel)

    gp._rng = check_random_state(gp.random_state)

    if gp.normalize_y:
        gp._y_train_mean = np.mean(y, axis=0)
        gp._y_train_std = np.std(y, axis=0)

        y = (y - gp._y_train_mean) / gp._y_train_std

    else:
        gp._y_train_mean = np.zeros(1)
        gp._y_train_std = 1

    if np.iterable(gp.alpha) and gp.alpha.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
        if gp.alpha.shape[0] == 1:
            gp.alpha = gp.alpha[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError("alpha must be a scalar or an array"
                             " with same number of entries as y.(%d != %d)"
                             % (gp.alpha.shape[0], y.shape[0]))

    gp.X_train_ = np.copy(X) if gp.copy_X_train else X
    gp.y_train_ = np.copy(y) if gp.copy_X_train else y

    if gp.optimizer is not None and gp.kernel_.n_dims > 0:

        def obj_func(theta, eval_gradient=True):
            if eval_gradient:
                lml, grad = alt_log_marginal_likelihood(gp, theta, eval_gradient=True, clone_kernel=True)
                return -lml, -grad
            else:
                return -alt_log_marginal_likelihood(gp, theta, clone_kernel=True)

        optima = [(gp._constrained_optimization(obj_func, gp.kernel_.theta, gp.kernel_.bounds))]

        if gp.n_restarts_optimizer > 0:
            if not np.isfinite(gp.kernel_.bounds).all():
                raise ValueError("Multiple optimizer restarts (n_restarts_optimizer>0) requires that all bounds are finite.")
            bounds = gp.kernel_.bounds
            for iteration in range(gp.n_restarts_optimizer):
                theta_initial = gp._rng.uniform(bounds[:, 0], bounds[:, 1])
                optima.append(gp._constrained_optimization(obj_func, theta_initial, bounds))

        lml_values = list(map(itemgetter(1), optima))
        gp.kernel_.theta = optima[np.argmin(lml_values)][0]

        gp.log_marginal_likelihood_value_ = -np.min(lml_values)
    else:
        gp.log_marginal_likelihood_value_ = alt_log_marginal_likelihood(gp, gp.kernel_.theta, clone_kernel=True)

    K = gp.kernel_(gp.X_train_)
    K[np.diag_indices_from(K)] += gp.alpha
    try:
        gp.L_ = cholesky(K, lower=True)  # Line 2
        gp._K_inv = None
    except np.linalg.LinAlgError as exc:
        exc.args = ("The kernel, %s, is not returning a "
                    "positive definite matrix. Try gradually "
                    "increasing the 'alpha' parameter of your "
                    "GaussianProcessRegressor estimator."
                    % gp.kernel_,) + exc.args
        raise
    gp.alpha_ = cho_solve((gp.L_, True), gp.y_train_)  # Line 3
    return gp

X = np.array((-5.09717005e+00,-4.97371994e+00,-4.90522017e+00,-4.76561902e+00,-4.67691785e+00,-4.54340855e+00,-4.47258867e+00,-4.37597423e+00,-4.26686261e+00,-4.17197691e+00,-3.99791328e+00,-3.97123439e+00,-3.79411596e+00,-3.74365655e+00,-3.63353746e+00,-3.52356937e+00,-3.46841329e+00,-3.28546064e+00,-3.22201979e+00,-3.09407224e+00,-2.97760593e+00,-2.93012849e+00,-2.78277215e+00,-2.69112708e+00,-2.66146750e+00,-2.55933162e+00,-2.38965976e+00,-2.29507762e+00,-2.16632907e+00,-2.14792914e+00,-2.00087737e+00,-1.93692937e+00,-1.76566894e+00,-1.73169083e+00,-1.54399602e+00,-1.47022061e+00,-1.34075771e+00,-1.32753621e+00,-1.15529292e+00,-1.09658954e+00,-9.66129799e-01,-8.36047383e-01,-7.37663792e-01,-6.70379935e-01,-5.77235907e-01,-5.00116512e-01,-3.62700012e-01,-2.51988573e-01,-1.39697953e-01,-4.37808815e-02,+8.03814053e-02,+1.83303592e-01,+3.00678855e-01,+3.82356967e-01,+4.74142871e-01,+5.80786139e-01,+6.56322792e-01,+7.48888247e-01,+8.30761981e-01,+9.92463873e-01,+1.08551669e+00,+1.20559816e+00,+1.28581523e+00,+1.35538103e+00,+1.51986166e+00,+1.57229312e+00,+1.67100322e+00,+1.75514038e+00,+1.84515657e+00,+2.02161206e+00,+2.11086824e+00,+2.19530943e+00,+2.29571550e+00,+2.41376546e+00,+2.51742391e+00,+2.63982950e+00,+2.73989004e+00,+2.82681192e+00,+2.89377000e+00,+3.03091821e+00,+3.07864347e+00,+3.26376424e+00,+3.37361362e+00,+3.39946483e+00,+3.49132403e+00,+3.61596989e+00,+3.70512010e+00,+3.79136456e+00,+3.98995451e+00,+4.01805376e+00,+4.17349187e+00,+4.23815199e+00,+4.33461262e+00,+4.49142727e+00,+4.53227252e+00,+4.67593419e+00,+4.79455493e+00,+4.82796882e+00,+4.92600534e+00,+5.01985017e+00))
X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array((+2.77877424e+01,+2.48739078e+01,+2.57826114e+01,+3.17313269e+01,+3.63057704e+01,+4.02729149e+01,+3.98560991e+01,+3.62633692e+01,+2.92636442e+01,+2.26970723e+01,+1.59841701e+01,+1.59335926e+01,+2.16587881e+01,+2.44134295e+01,+2.98843638e+01,+3.23060871e+01,+3.18335943e+01,+2.30039205e+01,+1.86324052e+01,+1.12698526e+01,+8.96496488e+00,+9.53394799e+00,+1.56992062e+01,+2.08574751e+01,+2.23635987e+01,+2.58633207e+01,+2.34019619e+01,+1.80619753e+01,+9.67462276e+00,+8.63098130e+00,+4.00366220e+00,+4.52668010e+00,+1.21346680e+01,+1.41466166e+01,+2.20042686e+01,+2.19870090e+01,+1.71960353e+01,+1.64436611e+01,+5.72909944e+00,+2.98825178e+00,+1.15899978e+00,+5.55202711e+00,+1.13184788e+01,+1.52460131e+01,+1.91786100e+01,+2.02501138e+01,+1.66355828e+01,+1.01884407e+01,+3.63066416e+00,+3.77891270e-01,+1.25496446e+00,+5.96452667e+00,+1.32211156e+01,+1.75364564e+01,+2.00931269e+01,+1.90764765e+01,+1.59826585e+01,+1.06306866e+01,+5.83072947e+00,+9.96192975e-01,+2.58749742e+00,+8.69966674e+00,+1.38847129e+01,+1.79850279e+01,+2.22322121e+01,+2.14580925e+01,+1.75544557e+01,+1.27575941e+01,+7.77563531e+00,+4.17897190e+00,+6.78552043e+00,+1.14503031e+01,+1.81033636e+01,+2.43939397e+01,+2.62775562e+01,+2.33511903e+01,+1.81417978e+01,+1.33498195e+01,+1.05199577e+01,+9.37456658e+00,+1.06742362e+01,+2.15159119e+01,+2.83904739e+01,+2.96267206e+01,+3.21744890e+01,+3.05359097e+01,+2.65105789e+01,+2.18045944e+01,+1.59396496e+01,+1.62090247e+01,+2.27939041e+01,+2.72181869e+01,+3.38583153e+01,+4.01584157e+01,+4.03366107e+01,+3.63518883e+01,+3.02247111e+01,+2.86039723e+01,+2.53269640e+01,+2.52765732e+01))
x = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(-5.12, 5.12, 1000)).T

kernel = C(1.0, (1e-3, 1e3)) * RBF(10, (1e-2, 1e2))
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=10, normalize_y=True, alpha=1.0E-10)

gp = alt_fit(gp, X, y)
print("LML: " + str(gp.log_marginal_likelihood_value_))

y_pred, sigma = gp.predict(x, return_std=True)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(X, y, 'r.', markersize=10, label='Observations')
plt.plot(x, y_pred, 'b-', label='Prediction')
plt.fill(np.concatenate([x, x[::-1]]), np.concatenate([y_pred - 1.9600 * sigma, (y_pred + 1.9600 * sigma)[::-1]]), alpha=.5, fc='b', ec='None', label='95% confidence interval')
plt.xlabel('$x$')
plt.ylabel('$f(x)$')
plt.ylim(-20, 50)
plt.legend(loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, there looks like a numerical error, so the question of a better model may not be valid here. Also, GPs are extremely flexible models, so if you try to fit a well-defined function, it is most likely to give you numerical errors. I checked with your code that inducing small noise in data works fine and it is okay to have LML negative. Also, just in case if you are curious, Scikit-learn is not a mature library to do GP stuff. You may want to see GPy, GPFlow, GPyTorch, PyMC3 etc.